# Comma separate a list whilst removing items

Tags: groovy

In Python I can collapse a list into a string with:

```
",".join([line for line in text if line != 'tests'])
```

Which I perceive as being a very elegant way of creating a CSV line.

Now I want to do the same in Groovy for use in a Jenkins DSL script. So far the best I have been able to achieve is:

```
def dirlist = "git ls-tree -d --name-only ${branchName}".execute(null, workingDir)
dirlist.waitFor()

String packages = ''
dirlist.text.eachLine { line ->
    if (line != 'tests' && line.length() != 0) {
        packages += line + ','
    }
}
packages = packages.getAt(0..(packages.length() - 2))
```

This works but doesn't seem very elegant and I have to strip the final comma manually.

Is there a cleaner way of writing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with:

```
dirlist.text.readLines().findAll { line ->
    line != 'tests' && line.length() != 0
}.join(',')
```

Comment: I was about to come back and say something was missing from this when you edited the missing component in - perfect. Thanks.